# Find specific mongoldb document from nested array

Tags: mongodb

This is my document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "566193b0c9b5290f234242"
    },
    "name": "fake-name-1",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "real-name": "fake-name-1",
            "color": "fake-color-1"
        },
        {
            "real-name": "fake-name-2",
            "color": "fake-color-2",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "real-name": "fake-name-3",
            "color": "fake-color-3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm real newbie to MondoDb, and are trying to find the document where profiles contains a real-name with "MArtin43221" and active = true.

How do I create a search query for this?

I've tried:

```
{"profiles": ["real-name":"MArtin43221", "active":true]}
```

Comment: Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index). You'll use `db.collection.find({"profiles.real-name":"MArtin43221", "profiles.active":true"})`

Comment: This will give documents where real-name and active are spread across profile array. Wont get the 'and' feeling

Comment: How do I get the 'and' feeling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1):

Try [**`elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.collection.find({"profiles": {$elemMatch:{"real-name":"MArtin43221", "active":true}}})
```